# How to add GeoJSON data to a layer using LeafletJS' layer group and layer control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Following the LeafletJS [tutorial on layer control](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) I've setup the same code except I am using openstreets instead of Mapbox. I have that all working.

Now, I want to add my own overlay loaded with GeoJSON data. My data is in a separate javascript file
`<script src="dataBlackspots-mini2016.js"></script>`    where the var blackaus16Data is defined.  This is well tested and works in other circumstances.

I setup the following statements to add an additional overlay map

```
var testsix = L.geoJson(black16Data);
var testme = L.layerGroup(testsix);
```

And this control appears on my map but how do I hookup that GeoJSON so it appears on this layer?
I started with the following statement but it causes a fatal error.

> (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'addLayer')
> at i.addTo (Layer.js:52)

```
var testsix = L.geoJson(black16data).addTo(map);
```

I also tried the following

```
var testsix = L.geoJson(black26data);
var testme = L.layerGroup(testsix.addTo(map));
```

I've read a dozen other stackkoverflow examples related to layer controls and I've tried all sorts of variations but I just dont get it...I cannot hookup any geojson so that the data appears on a basemap or an overlay map when using the convention outlined in the tutorial.

I am new to both javascript and the whole mapping genre.

Here is my complete code and I have left in some commented code so that my modifications are more obvious.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Full Screen Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6d79777d2b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/leaflet-beautify-marker-icon.css"/>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   <script src="resources/leaflet-beautify-marker-icon.js"></script> 
   <script src="dataBlackspots-mini2016.js"></script>
   <script>
    
// The following variable is used to change the default marker using beautify marker plugin
    options2 = {
//            iconShape: 'rectangle-dot'
                iconShape: 'circle-dot'
               , borderWidth: 5
               , borderColor: '#FF073A'
        };
        
var adelaide = L.marker([-34.9998826,138.330985]).bindPopup('This is Adelaide, SA'),
    innam    = L.marker([-27.74951840398218, 140.74142561361253]).bindPopup('This is Innamminka, SA'),
    coober    = L.marker([-29.0076186,134.6811297]).bindPopup('This is Coober, SA'),
    tonsley    = L.marker([-35.0081757,138.5698093]).bindPopup('This is Tonsley, SA');
    
    var testsix = L.geoJson(black16Data);
//  testsix.addTo(map);

var cities = L.layerGroup([adelaide, innam, coober, tonsley]);
var testme = L.layerGroup(testsix);

// var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mapboxUrl, {id: 'MapID', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mapboxAttribution}),
//    streets   = L.tileLayer(mapboxUrl, {id: 'MapID', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mapboxAttribution});

// var osmlink = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';

var grayscale = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors', maxZoom: 18, });
var streets   = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors', maxZoom: 18, });



var baseMaps = {
    "Grayscale": grayscale,
    "Streets": streets,
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Cities": cities,
    "Test": testme
};

var map =   L.map('map', {
        layers: [grayscale, cities] 
 }).setView([-31.9410435,130.5127033], 6);  

        L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

            // testing font awesome for marker  WORKS!! the bright red spot
        L.marker([-34.9414961, 138.6584563], {
                icon: L.BeautifyIcon.icon(options2),
                draggable: true
                }).addTo(map).bindPopup("popup").bindPopup("This is a BeautifyMarker");
            
            
//  The following code has been tested.
//          L.geoJson(black16Data, {                    //Load 2016 data using font awesome for marker bright red
//              pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) 
//              {
//                  return L.marker(latlng, 
//                  {
//                      icon: L.BeautifyIcon.icon(options2)
//                  });
//              }
//              }).addTo(map);
//          L.geoJson(black18Data, {                    //Load 2018 data using font awesome for black marker
//              pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) 
//              {
//                  return L.marker(latlng, 
//                  {
//                      icon: L.BeautifyIcon.icon(options)
//                  });
//              }
//              }).addTo(map);

//debugger;         
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems that the leaflet object is still loading. try to start the leaflet operations only once everything is loaded. For example:
```document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// your leaflet code}```

Comment: Thank you for you time. This was not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this problem!  I deleted the following line of code

`var testsix = L.geoJson(black16Data);`

and I replaced this line
`var testme = L.layerGroup(testsix);`

with this  `var testme = L.geoJson(black16Data);`

My data now appears on the overlay called Test.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer that helped resolving your problem :)